# How is this not a Java visibility violation

Tags: java, debugging, linked-list, visibility

It is a simple implementation of linked list to split one list into two sublists. Other details have been discarded for simplicity

```
class SList {
    private head;
    Object item;

    public void split_list(SList list1, SList list2) {
         list1.head = this.head;
         // Some other stuff
    }

}
```

isn't it a visibility violation to do assign list1.head? To my surprise, I tried and it worked fine

Comment: sorry, I meant "split one list into two sublists"

Comment: Which violation you are expecting there?

Comment: You should accept some of your previously asked questions if you want your newer questions to get better attention.

Comment: This won't even compile. `private head` has no data type.

Comment: my bad i typed the code directly here so I am missing a few things.

My expected violation is: head is private to SList, so I didnt expect list1 to be able to access it outside its scope by using: list1.head

@DeviantSeev: thanks for the suggestion. I will check back my old questions and do as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JLS 6.6.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.8):

> A private class member or constructor is accessible only within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

It's the same class.

Comment: "within the body of the top level class" 

thanks, that line helped a lot. So outside in other functions/classes, trying to manipulate list1.head will be a violation

Comment: @Ethan Privates can't be access from other classes (including subclasses), correct. `private` really means `private_to_any_other_class's_instances` but the apostrophe isn't legal Java, so they changed it to just `private`.

Answer (score 4):

The `private` modifier means a member can only be accessed by the class itself, it's not restricted to an instance of that class. Also see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 1):

An instance of a class always has complete access to all members of other instances of the same class, regardless of their visibility. `private` means private to this *class*, not to this *object*.

Answer (score 0):

The modifier `private` of the member `head` means private to the **class** `SList`, not private to an **instance** of `SList` (defined in JLS 6.6.8, http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.8).